# Static string->string mapping

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, mapping

I need a string->string mapping to be used at runtime (think `NSDictionary`), except the mapping will NEVER change after build-time.

The naive solution is to just use an `NSDictionary`, but there has to be a more optimal way to do this, no?

Optimal in the sense that if the mapping is known at compile-time, and known to never change, the compiler should be able to do the mapping at compile-time. An NSDictionary needs to do a hash lookup at runtime. I know it's constant time, but it just feels a bit "unclean" to me...

Comment: "More optimal" in what sense? Do you see some performance problem with NSDictionary, or are you just assuming that there must be one?

Comment: Updated my question to clarify what I mean by "optimal".

Comment: How can the compiler do the mapping at compile time if the mapping is "to be used at runtime" as per your first sentence? Can you explain the problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I suppose something like an enum. Maybe I explained it wrong, but what I would like to be able to do (after giving it some more thought) is to map a string to a member of an enum. Which I'm not sure is possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static `NSDictionary` is the right tool for this. You typically initialize these with an `+initialize` method:

```
static NSDictionary *kDictionary;

+ (void)initialize {
  if (self == [MYClass class]) {
    kDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWith...];
  }
}
```

`initialize` is called one time per class, with thread safety, immediately before the first requested method is called on that class (usually this first method is `+alloc`). The `self` test is because subclasses will automatically call their `[super initialize]`, and you generally don't want to run this more than once in that case.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a `dispatch_once()` guard for the initialization instead? That seems more in line with the intended limit, and it would allow subclasses to be sure the dictionary is available (if one of them is used before this class).

Comment: Where would you put the `dispatch_once()`? You could put it in `init`, but what if the object is created using `initWithCoder:`? What if there are class methods that rely on the dictionary, which might be called prior to the first `init`? `+initialize` takes care of all these corner cases and so avoids subtle and difficult bugs. It's not good to do class initialization in an instance method. If you do it in a class method, why not `+initialize` which is called automatically at the right time?

Comment: Re-reading my comment, it seems quite unclear to me now. Sorry, I meant substituting `dispatch_once()` for `if( self == [MYClass class] )`, inside `+initialize`, _not_ moving the dictionary creation elsewhere. Then the first message to any class in the inheritance tree starting with this one would create the dictionary, and no others would re-create it. Is that right?

Comment: dispatch_once() would probably be fine here. `+initialize` is much older than GCD, and the class check is the traditional pattern. dispatch_once is an extra line of code, but it does have the advantage of not hard-coding the class name. (There are some things in ObjC that we do because that's how it's been done since NeXTSTEP; that doesn't mean we shouldn't reconsider it every few years....)

Comment: That's about what I figured. Thanks for the clarification. (I've only been using ObjC since OS X Puma or so -- the language has been moving fast the past few years!)

Answer (score 3):

You could hard code your `NSDictionary` if that isn't too cumbersome (i.e. it's not huge), or you could create a plist and include it in your app bundle. Then at app launch, read the dictionary from the plist (a couple lines of code). Each of these approaches is about the same effort. The advantage of using a plist is that if you have to change it, you are editing the plist, not code.

Comment: This is the way I've often due it in the past. However, it still feels dirty to me because you're doing runtime computation for something that is fully known at compile-time!

Comment: If the plist is large, the run time hit could be significant. But there are ways to push that processing to the background and mitigate any perceptible lag. On the other hand, what do you want to maintain: code or a plist? The answers here depend somewhat on the nature and size of the data.

Comment: Good point, Mark. I agree that maintaining a PLIST is preferable, but the amount of data in this case is small. However, I will probably end up going the PLISt route for simplicity and readability.